# What is ^I in Pascal?

Tags: pascal

I don't know what is `^I` and `^G` in a **Pascal** program.

Here:

```
const TAB = ^I;
```

and

```
WriteLn(^G, ' Error : ' , s, ' . ' );
```

Comment: Thanks H.P for edit my post

Comment: In that context, `^` stands for the `Ctrl` key on the keyboard.

Comment: In some Pascals (like Turbo Pascal, Delphi, FreePascal), like MartynA says, `^` stands for `Ctrl`, so `^A` is the same as `#1` or `Chr(1)`, `^G` is `#7`, etc. `^G` is the `BELL` ASCII character, which usually produces a short beep, on platforms that recognize it. `^I` is indeed the horizontal tab character (`#9`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that context, ^ stands for the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key on the keyboard.  To demonstrate, go to a CMD prompt and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and `G` at the same time.

The other usage is as indicated in the other answer, i.e. as an indirection operator for pointers.

Comment: No, in Pascal, `^` is not used in mathematical expressions as exponentiation operator. There is a `**` operator in Extended Pascal which does this, but not in any other Pascal I know.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis:  Thanks for the correction.  I'm not sure where I got the exponentiation operator idea from, pseudo-code listings or similar maybe, so I've removed the reference from my answer.

Answer (score -3):

caret(^) is for a pointer variable.

[Read more](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refse15.html)

Comment: Not iin the context the OP quotes.